# Stacking vs Non-stacking architectures in deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, tf.keras

In Keras (or deep learning in its entirety), what is the difference between a `stacking` and a `non-stacking` architecture and can anyone give a simple illustration of a `non-stacking` architecture?

There are quite a lot of examples and tutorials showing how to stack layers in keras but there's really none about what the opposite of stacking is.

Answer (score 1):

Deep neural networks are, by definition, stacks of neural networks (generally just called layers). You might think of it as a series of operations; a flowchart. For example, in object detection networks, series' of convolution layers (called feature pyramids) is used to extract regional features from images. Just like a flow chart, however, you can create branches, and move the data along however you prefer. Consider the following code snippets:

Just a stack.

```
input_layer = InputLayer(input_shape=(256,256,3))
x = Dense(666)(input_layer)
x = Dense(666)(x)
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Something more interesting.

```
input_layer = Inputlayer(input_shape=(256,256,3))
x = Dense(666)(input_layer)

x_left = Dense(666)(x) # gets inputs from x
x_left = Dense(666)(x_left)

x_right = Dense(666)(x)
x_right = Dense(666)(x_right)

x = concatenate([x_left,x_right],axis=-1)

x = Dense(666)(x)
output_layer = Dense(1,activation='softmax')(x)
```

Does that answer your question at all?

Also, this graphic might help; this is a basic feature pyramid network layout I found on Google that does a decent job of depicting:
[image: feature pyramids]